# How to access a global variable in a different function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a global variable 'input' and it's value is assigned in the function
`processinput`. But if I try to access the value `input` inside a different function, the value is displayed undefined.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visualization</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Your CSS styles here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="graph-container">
      <div id="network" class="main-panel"></div>
      <div id="graph" class="side-panel">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label for="quantity">Enter the value</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity">
    <button id="submit" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>

    <script>
      var input;
      function processInput() {
        input = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        console.log(input);
      }

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Rest of your code...
        console.log(input);
        // Fetch JSON data, initialize graph, and set up event listeners

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Suggestions on how to access the value of `input` outside `processInput` function will be really helpful.

EDIT:
Thanks for the comments. For instance, if I try to display the value of `input` outside the processInput function, it is undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visualization</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Your CSS styles here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="graph-container">
      <div id="network" class="main-panel"></div>
      <div id="graph" class="side-panel">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label for="quantity">Enter the value</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity">
    <button id="submit" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>

    <script>
      var input;
      function processInput() {
        input = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        console.log(input);
      }

      function test() {
        // Rest of your code...
        console.log(input);
        // Fetch JSON data, initialize graph, and set up event listeners

      };
      console.log(input);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the time `DOMContentLoaded` fires, no one will have had the time to enter anything into the field. Your code would otherwise work fine.

Comment: In your provided code, it seems like you're trying to log the value of input right after the document is ready (`DOMContentLoaded`). However, the value of `input` is only set when the `processInput()` function is called - that is, when the "Submit" button is clicked.

Comment: @ErhanÇapar Could you please see the edit? I would like to know how to access the value of the global variable outside the processInput function.

Comment: You never call the `test` function

Comment: @Natasha Just typing the name of the variable is enough in order to access the variable outside the `processInput` function, as the variable is defined outside of the function.

Comment: @Konrad My doubt is if `input` value is set inside the `processInput` function, can I access it elsewhere. Example, I tried to do       console.log(input);
outside the function (please see line below test function).

Comment: @Natasha Again, by the time that last `console.log(input)` fires, no one will have had the time to call `processInput` to assign a value.

Comment: Time travel doesn't exist

Comment: @AKX thank you for the clarification. Could you please suggest how the code should be modified to get it working? I'm sorry for the naive question.

Comment: Why do you want to access the value of that input globally?

Comment: @Konrad Thanks. I want to access the value of the `input` globally because I am assigning value to another variable based on this value 
               ` var nscale = [input * 0.1, input, input * 10];` but outside the processInput function.

Comment: @Natasha Right, so then... just do that inside the function? What would you do with that `nscale` then?

Comment: @AKX `nscale` array is used to define `steps` for defining sliders of a plotly.js network graph https://plotly.com/javascript/sliders/ . If I include the rest of the script in the processInput function, then the plotly graph is no visible in the frontend.

Comment: @Natasha It would become visible as soon as you entered the value. But you'll have to look at an API in Plotly to _change_ the `steps` for the graph create...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your global input variable has no value on page load. And it will never have a value just after you assign something to it. Which you do but in your `processInput()` function which only called on submit button click.

Javascript runs as soon as you load the page and it will print the undefined global input variable before you even call the `processInput()` function.

I suggest that you assign a value as soon as the javascript runs like this:

```
<script>

// This way your input will contain a reference to the element which has an id of "quantity"
var inputElem = document.getElementById("quantity");

// Prints nothing because the input element has no assigned default value
console.log( inputElem.value );

</script>
```

In your process input function you can assign a value to an other variable if you want to, something like this:

```
<script>

var inputElem = document.getElementById("quantity");
var inputText;

/*
This function will be called on submit button click and it will add
the value of the inputElem to the inputText variable. Later you can 
use inputText anywhere.
*/
function processInput(){
    inputText = inputElem.value;
}

// The below code still prints nothing because the processInput() function does not run at this point in time.
console.log(inputText);    

</script>
```